# Allow only one br in nl2br

Tags: php

I let my members of my website to post some information about them in textarea. I use function `nl2br` to be it more prettier, smth like that:

```
$text_of_area = nl2br($_POST['text_area_name']); //yeah, of course i use functions against xss, sql injection attacks

mysql_query("..."); //here I insert a text
```

But here is problem. I don't want to allow people to use more then one enter (br) allowed in text, so what can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just replace more than one new line away prior to calling nl2br?

If you want to let them use only one new line at all in their post:

```
$firstPos = strpos($text, "\n");
if ($firstPos !== false) {
    $text = substr_replace(array("\r","\n"),'', $text, $firstPos + 1);
}
$text = nl2br($text);
```

If you want to let them use only one consecutive new line (allowing `foo\nbar\nbaz`):

```
$text = preg_replace('#[\r\n]+#', "\n", $text);
$text = nl2br($text);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do:

```
$text_of_area = nl2br(str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $_POST['text_area_name']));
```